# python3.7 JSON reading data format exception

Tags: python, json

## test code

```
import json

body = '{"body1": {"value_range": "0-1","value": 5e-4},"body2": {"value_range": "0-1","value": 5e-5},"body3": {' \
       '"value_range": "0-1","value": 5e-6}} '
json_body = json.loads(body)
print(json_body)
```

## print

```
{'body1': {'value_range': '0-1', 'value': 0.0005}, 'body2': {'value_range': '0-1', 'value': 5e-05}, 'body3': {'value_range': '0-1', 'value': 5e-06}}
```

## Question

**why the format of the 'value' change**
5e-4 --> 0.0005
5e-5 --> 5e-05
5e-6 --> 5e-06

**If my input is nonstandard, is there any way to make my output consistent with input**
such as:
5e-2 --> 5e-2
0.0005 --> 0.0005
5e-5 --> 5e-5

Comment: Because the values are converted to actual `float`s. If you use the REPL and input `5e-4` `5e-5` and `5e-6`, you will also get `0.0005` `5e-05` and `5e-06`.

Comment: Because Python only shows numbers with  scientific notation if they have more than 3 zeroes after the decimal point.

Comment: You can use string formatting to standardize the output, assuming you know what format the input is in.

`5e-2` will produce `0.05` in the REPL. `"{:.0e}".format(5e-2)` will produce `5e-02`. As far as I know there is no way to remove the leading 0 on the exponent, and it's standard practice to include it anyhow. Changing the digit before the `e` in the formatting string will change the number of significant digits in the output.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert them to scientific notation again:

```
from decimal import Decimal

'%.0E' % Decimal('0.0005')
```